# How to map values from array to use in for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

How I can turn this

```
Array
(
    [0] => feed
    [1] => entry
)
```

into this:

```
foreach ($data->feed->entry as $item) { // Yep, we made it }
```

The first array can have any number of values, so solution needs to be flexible.

EDIT:
Dogbert gave me perfect answer, but to make this more clear for future. What I have is only one array. Based on that I need to get array from object. So my array might look like this also:

```
[0] => world
[1] => countries
[2] => finland
[3] => helsinki
[4] => people
```

And then I would need to get:

```
foreach ($data->world->countries->finland->helsinki->people as $item) {}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide much more information. `foreach` is for iterating over arrays. I.e. if `$data` is this array and you have `foreach ($data as $item)`, then `$item` will have the values `feed` and `entry`. I don't see how you want to get from the array structure you posted to `$data->feed->entry`.

Comment: What is wrong with this? Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: I tried to keep my question short and straight to the point. Sorry that it was misleading. I added another example just to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function map_property($obj, $array) {
  $ret = $obj;
  foreach($array as $prop) {
    $ret = $ret->$prop;
  }
  return $ret;
}

foreach(map_property($data, array('feed', 'entry')) as $item) { }
```

Comment: Ah... that might make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need key => value in loop do it like this:

```
foreach ($data->feed->entry as $key=>$item) {
// Yep, we made it
echo 'This is key:'.$key.' this is item: '.$item;
}
```

you will get result

This is key: 0 this is item: feedThis is key: 1 this is item: entry